# Push Notification doesn't works for iPhone to Android Message Alerts

Tags: android, ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to set up AWS SNS push notifications in my iOS App. My question pertains to sending a notification request to SNS from iOS to an Android endpoint. When I try to send a notification request I get the following error.

```
Message=Invalid parameter: Message Reason: Invalid notification for protocol GCM: data/notification payload is malformed.
```

I think it may be because I am not converting the Android device token correctly for the request payload. I am trying to do it the way I send iOS to iOS notification request but the same approach does not work and results in the error above. Does the device Token need to be converted to hexadecimal? Is the format of GCM Payload correct and do we need to do anything related to device token generated. Below is a typical Android device token and my notification payload setup for referen.  Please advise?
Android device token

```
("eV6Hxl-1RpizD0uLQiUDLi:APA91bFtlJB4QNV5_J44loN3icHLc63DvhxYuhd2_XEi--1CJxcJAKhQYKOdOWipdeHiRhk455JrBlFSoj2AubbCSfEiZaG1gw3gKKHe0ZUXpBXkcXopwy3lOcybWnHXxz8BVdUa6xIh")
```

GCM Payload I am using is

```
 func gcmPayload(message: String,flagName: String, requestId: String, flagId: Int) -> [String: Any]{
        var payLoad = [String: Any]()
       payLoad = ["GCM":"{\"data\":{\"title\":\"\(message)\":\"body\":\"\(flagName)\":\"flagId\":\"\(flagId)\":\"requestId\":\"\(requestId)\"}:\"priority\":\"high\"}"]
        return payLoad
    }
```

My push notification works for iPhone devices using APNS. There I convert the deviceToken generated to Base64 in hexadecimal format, but this does not seem to work for Android device token values. Also, when I try to publish the message to SNS, I get an error message that states Message=Invalid parameter: Message Reason: Invalid notification for protocol GCM: data/notification payload is malformed.